# Can I use open cv with python on Google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, opencv, python-2.7

HI actually I was working on a project which i intended to deploy on the google appengine.
However I found that google app engine is supported by python. Can I run openCV  with python scripts on Google app engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. GAE only supports either pure python extensions or extensions that they are supplying themselves.

OpenCV uses C, so it is not suitable.

> The interpreter can run any Python code, including Python modules you include with your application, as well as the Python standard library. The interpreter cannot load Python modules with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview

[Pure Python and GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Pure_Python)

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul C your answer .

Answer (score 4):

No. OpenCV is a Python wrapper to a C++ library, and Google App Engine can only run pure Python code.

Google App Engine [accepted this issue on May 9, 2012](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7010), but it has not gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot frb for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Now it is possible. The app should be deployed using a custom runtime in the GAE flexible environment. OpenCV library can be installed by adding the instruction `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-opencv` in the Dockerfile.